# Windows Server 2022 Hyper-V VM disk performance

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2022

I have some Windows Server 2022 VMs on few Hyper-V 2019 (DELL R720, R730, T430) servers. I'm observing strange performance issues on dynamically expanding VHDX virtual disks.
When dynamically expanding disk is used within the Windows Server 2022 VM, I can't get more than 200MB/s sequential write speed regardless of physical storage used. Measured by CrystalDiskMark software.
I'm not observing that on fixed virtual disk, or older versions of Windows Server (2019,2016) even if dynamically expanding virtual disk is used.
Do you observe that also? Or do you know any fix?
For testing I uninstalled Windows Defender, it doesn't help.